# React-Native Linking AddEventListener not working

Tags: react-native

Hi I was trying to use React-Native's Linking library to listen to Linking changes and I followed the instructions on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html. I can open external URL using openURL but Linking.addEventListener doesn't seem to work for me. 
I copied the code snippet:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  Linking.addEventListener('url', this._handleOpenURL);
},
componentWillUnmount() {
  Linking.removeEventListener('url', this._handleOpenURL);
},
_handleOpenURL(event) {
  console.log(event.url);
}
```

it doesn't give me an error but the _handleOpenURL is not called when the app opens up a external URL.

I wonder why is this case and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Did you figure out the problem, I am running into the same thing.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Does anyone have any solution on this?

Comment: @FreddieCabrera  Hi! Yes, it turns out linking only working inside custom webview inside the app, so if you opens up the link in a web browser, the linking lib will not be able to listen to the events happening outside the app. Linking listener only works on webview inside the app.

Comment: @Zip see the above comment :)

Comment: @DanqiLiao It could be non-sense, then why React Native base documentation using Linking.OpenURL? It should work outside either. Can you write details about it?

Comment: @DanqiLiao That would defeat the purpose of the link. Facebook says: Linking gives you a general interface to interact with both incoming and outgoing app links.

Comment: @DanqiLiao It will be called if your app gets opened from a url! e.g: having an html button in some website to open your app

Answer (score 17):

This is because Linking have a specific method when the app start through a intent.

Try with this:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  Linking.getInitialURL().then((ev) => {
    if (ev) {
      this._handleOpenURL(ev);
    }
  }).catch(err => {
      console.warn('An error occurred', err);
  });
  Linking.addEventListener('url', this._handleOpenURL);
}
```

Comment: in my case, Linking.getInitialURL() works if the app opened by a url, but when the app is already opened , Linking.addEventListener() doesn't work

Comment: Thanks, just copy and paste on top level component, and works (also works with already opened app). I use android, do not need edit other files like iOS (AppDelegate.m).

Comment: With this code you'll be sending _handleOpenURL two different types of value. addEventListener('url') sends it an event. Linking.getInitialURL will pass through a string url.

Comment: It is working perfectly in android. I didnt check in ios

Comment: in mycase, On android studio amulator sometimes not working, but real device works

Comment: @FakhruddinAbdi I'm facing the same problem. Do you have any solution for that?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem that I managed to fix for 2 days. Here are my steps, I hope it will help to the next one that needs to manage to fix this problem.

1. Go to the React Native Documentation for your version
   (**IMPORTANT**) -  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/versions
2. Go to **Linking** API documentation (Follow the steps)

In my case, I just added this method

```
// iOS 9.x or newer
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}
```

After that, the event listener will work properly. Check the IOS version there is a snippet for 8.x and bellow.

Comment: just to complete this answer. If you use FBSDK you may have to check if FBSDK dont catch the deeplink https://stackoverflow.com/a/48189383/7230188

Answer (score 2):

I'm using bare workflow and this is how I implement Linking event listener to my functional component.

1. [Set up Deep linking for a bare React Native projects](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/#set-up-with-bare-react-native-projects). You can also find instruction for Expo project on the document.
2. Add Linking event listener to `useEffect` hook.

   ```js
   useEffect(() => {
      const linkingEvent = Linking.addEventListener('url', handleDeepLink);
      Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
         if (url) {
            handleDeepLink({url});
         }
      });
      return () => {
         linkingEvent.remove();
      };
   }, [handleDeepLink]);

   const handleDeepLink = async (url) => {
      // add your code here
   }
   ```

Comment: This doesn't work when the app is in the background and a deeplink is triggered

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has ejected from expo - you DON'T need to add this code to AppDelegate (unlike it stated in the documentation here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.60/linking). I don't know why this works and I'm not sure why the documentation doesn't state this.. perhaps it's assuming you haven't ejected.

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
 return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                  continueUserActivity:userActivity
                    restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}
```

Just leave it like so

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
  return [super application:application continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}
```

As soon as I removed it `Linking.addEventListener('url', this._handleOpenURL);` started working for me.

Comment: Unfortunately changing this code had no impact for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);     
    this.setIntent(intent);
}
```

Use this in ManActivity.java to open the app while in foreground or background

Answer (score -1):

Try use `Linking.removeAllListeners('url');` to remove

I use in my project and it works:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Linking.addEventListener('url', _handleOpenURL);
    return () => {
      Linking.removeAllListeners('url');
    };
  }, []);
```