# React Native Deep Link Event Listener Not firing

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-linking

```
  componentDidMount() {
    Linking.addEventListener('url', event => 
    this.handleOpenURL(event.url));
    Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
     console.log('url===',url);
     if(url)
      this.handleOpenURL(url);
   });
  }
```

handleOpenUrl is never called if the app is already open and I try to change the deep link Url. If the app is already not open then it opens the app and gets the URL.

Answer (score 4):

Actually it was the issue with FBSDK overriding the method.

This solution worked for me.
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/798#issuecomment-290363058

Comment: hmm, ok. I still leave the answer for explanation as lifecycles if someone else needs that (unless it's downvoted :/)

Comment: If i were you i'd remove it. Because I know didmount is called once but it should register the event and event should trigger!

Comment: Could you maybe provide the code in the anwer directly with the entire snippet? @Pavan

Comment: The code is there in the github issue link. It's objective C code and I don't understand it so I refrained from copying. I just put a link

Comment: @Pavan realy thx !! i've been looking a long time to figure out why its was not workong only on IOS. FBSDK was the problem !!

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue working on a detached Expo project because I had added the suggested code from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html to the `*AppDelegate.m` but Expo already provides slightly different functions for handling URL events. Removing the code from the React Native docs made it work for me.